# Change base volume of device (Windows 8)?

Tags: windows-8, usb, audio, volume-mixer

I own an USB speaker, since I found the audio quality of builtin speakers far from sufficient. Sadly however, it doesn't have an analogue volume control. The volume buttons on the device simply change the software-side device volume by steps of 2 per cent points, as do the volume keys of the notebook.

Sadly however, the USB-device is way too loud. At "4%" it equals roughly the 100% setting of the notebook. The hardware volume keys allow only settings 0,2,4,6... per cent, but even 1 per cent is often too loud, especially when software (e.g. old games or some websites) don't allow an additional level of volume control.

Is there some way in Windows 8 to change the base volume of a device, such that "100%" is as loud as "10%" was before, such that I can access loudness settings that would currently correspond to "1.5%", using the normal volume controls of my device? Note again, I don't want to set the volume to 10% in the volume mixer, I want to make the "100%" setting less loud.

Even better would be a solution that replaces the standard linear volume scale by a logarithmic scale, such that pressing "Vol+" has the same relative effect at low volume as it has at high volume.

Detail information:
  OS: Windows 8, USB-Device: Logitech Z305